# SmtpClient: How do I get failed delivery notifications?

Tags: c#, email, error-handling, smtp

I want the users who send mail from my application to be able to be notified of failures as well as pull reporting for all mail sent from their account.

But this question is focused on the getting back failed delivery notifications, how would I setup something that listens for them so I could then modify the sent email log in my database to reflect this?

Comment: @Carnotaurus any chance you could give more detail? an answer would probably be better than a comment if this is the solution, thanks!

Comment: Not really - SMTP is about *sending* mails only. If you want to catch bounce messages, you'd have to set up a mail account where those bounce messages would be sent to, and then you need to check that account on a regular basis, using POP3 or IMAP, and parse/interpret the bounce messages you get mailed there...

Comment: @marc_s thank you, I'll see about polling a POP3 account from my web app, you wouldn't happen to know any .NET libraries that exist for this kind of thing would you?

Comment: Ok, take a look at the section on domain validation: http://www.webonweboff.com/tips/asp/email.aspx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since marc_s just used a comment, I'll go ahead and put an answer here.

An SMTP Client is just responsible for sending messages, and gets very little feedback as to the success status of the message. It'll get an exception if the SMTP Server is down or something, but usually the SMTP Server itself handles the actual sending attempts.

Comment: even though you are correct, you forgot a small part which i think the OP was looking for. how do you specify the bounce back email address? if you don't specify it, the bounce will get back to the sender address, which will cause a lot more parsing of emails.

Comment: @Dementic: It depends on how you send the emails. If you set the "From" email address to an address that you have control over (which I would argue you should), then it will bounce back to that address automatically.  If you use the user's actual third-party email address, you'll have to do contortions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2077135/how-to-set-the-bounce-address-using-system-net-mail